# Azure Active Directory enforce graph endpoint instead of groups claim

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, signalr, claims-based-identity

According to the documentation, if a user is a memeber of 200 groups or more, by dedault the JWT token that will be returned will not contain the `groups` claim; It will contain `_claim_names` and `_claim_sources` instead with an endpoint to Microsoft graph. This behaviour is used in order to reduce the token size in case of groups overage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/zero-trust/develop/configure-tokens-group-claims-app-roles)

In our case, for some users, the JWT token is too large (it contains 100 groups memebership or so, but not 200) and we need to find a way to make the token smaller.

The reason for the limitation is that the generated JWT token is sent to SignalR service which the max token size allowed is 4K.

Is there a way to enforce AAD to return a JWT token without the groups claim and instead it will return the `_claim_names` and `_claim_sources`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Follow the guidance provided on this doc [Configure group claim for Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#group-filtering) and apply the Group filtering to allow you to control the list of groups that's included as part of the group claim.